# bin/hadoop version throws an error in CYGWIN [WIndows 7]

Tags: windows, hadoop, cygwin, bigdata

When i execute the following command:

> Anands@Tx-D-AnandS /usr/local/hadoop-1.1.2
>
> $ bin/hadoop version

I get the following error:

```
cygwin warning:
    MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Program_Files\Java\jre6\x0D/bin/java
    Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Program_Files/Java/jre6\x0D/bin/java
    CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
    Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
    /bin/java: No such file or directoryes\Java\jre6
    /bin/java: No such file or directoryes\Java\jre6
    /bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directorye6
```

Can anyone help me with this? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

set the system environment variable for java

Also set `export JAVA_HOME=c:/Program_Files/Java/jre6` in hadoop-evn.sh file.